# How to use variable as an interval for timer?

Tags: vb.net, timer

I'm creating an automated program and I'm stucked with the timer. When I started the program it just says that the interval is 0

here's what I got:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim TextBox1 As String
    Dim URL As String
    Dim Textbox3 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Times As Integer
    Dim Time As Integer
    Dim Textbox2 As Integer
    Dim rampTimer As New Timer
    Dim Tyme As Integer
Restart:
    TextBox1 = URL
    UseProxy(ListBox1.Items.Item(i))
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL)
    Tyme = Textbox3 * 1000 * 6
    rampTimer.Interval = Tyme
    rampTimer.Enabled = True
    Time = Times + 1
    If Time = Textbox2 Then
        MsgBox("Done! Made by Laboboy31", "Done")
        GoTo Last
    End If
    Times = Time
    GoTo Restart
Last:
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow.  I've not seen code this bad since my days on IRC several decades ago.  Are you pranking us?

Comment: no i'm just a newbie in vb.net

Comment: Oh.  Well.  Ok.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Lets see if we can't get you straightened out.  Can you explain the purpose of your code?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create a website viewer for my site

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you can explain what you want to do I'm sure we can help.

Comment: i'm creating an automated website viewer that uses proxies

Comment: I'm looking for a paragraph or two describing the purpose of the code and how you envision it working.

Comment: "web site viewer that uses proxies" isn't enough to go on.  I'm seeing referneces to timers in your code, and your description makes me think, "well why dont you just use IE Chrome".  DETAILS are what we need.

Comment: The program must browse the website for a x amount of time and x amount of views with proxy support. The purpose of this program is to increase the seo of my site

Answer (score 4):

Taking a bit of a wild guess here, but I suspect your main issue is around this sort of thing

```
Dim TextBox3 as Integer
    Tyme = Textbox3 * 1000 * 6
    rampTimer.Interval = Tyme
```

Now I'm guessing you have a textbox on your form, called "textbox3".
First rename it to something meaningful Like ClickInterval. and all the other windows components you are going to refer to in the code.

TextBox3 in your routine is the integer you declared with the dim statement. Because its an Integer, it gets initialised to 0, so Tyme = 0 * 1000 * 6, which is 0...

So given you do have a TextBox called TextBox3, that's the component itself. If you want the content
then you'd refer to TextBox3.Text.

Last but not least TextBox.Text is a string, so you need to convert it to an integer(and deal with it not being one). 
so get rid of the dim statement and try

```
ramptimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.text) * 1000 * 6
```

if I'm on the right lines.